# How does KDE determine my language?

Tags: arch-linux, language, kde

I use ArchLinux with KDE. When I the system settings, for example, it looks like this:

[image]

As you see some part of it is in English, some part in German.

From that I deduce two questions:

- Why are **two** languages used here?
- How did KDE determine my language? I don't remember to have been asked anywhere where I am or what my native language is. Or is it ArchLinux providing this information to KDE?